# How to turn this send mail command from Posfix to Ssmtp?

Tags: email, ssmtp

I am new to superuser and I got stuck to turn mail command from Posfix to Ssmtp. Here is the command I am solving. THANKS SO MUCH in advance.

```
00 08 * * * tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/mydomain-access.log | awk '$11 !~   /google|bing|yahoo|yandex|mywebsite.com/' | awk '{print $11}' | tr -d '"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1000 | mail -s "Top 1000 Referers for Mydomain.com" me@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail` calling `sendmail` program to delivery email (it could be substituted with `postfix`, `exim`, `msmtp` and other). In most cases  `sendmail` is a symlink that point to program you want.

You can find location of `sendmail` by issuing `whereis sendmail` and overwrite it to location of `ssmtp`

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

'ssmtp: /usr/sbin/ssmtp /etc/ssmtp /usr/share/man/man8/ssmtp.8.gz'

sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail/usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.8.gz

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Here is the output. But I don't know how is it related to my question. I need to modify this code to send mail with ssmtp. Can you have a look? Thank you so much.
`00 08 * * * tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/mydomain-access.log | awk '$11 !~   /google|bing|yahoo|yandex|mywebsite.com/' | awk '{print $11}' | tr -d '"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1000 | mail -s "Top 1000 Referers for Mydomain.com" me@mydomain.com`
`ssmtp: /usr/sbin/ssmtp /etc/ssmtp /usr/share/man/man8/ssmtp.8.gz`
`sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail/usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.8.gz`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use `ssmtp` instead of `postfix` and you want to send email from `cron` by utilizing `mail` command, right? If yes, then do this: `cp -af /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/sbin/sendmail.bak && ln -sf /usr/sbin/ssmtp  /usr/sbin/sendmail`. From now on, your machine will use `ssmtp` instead of `postfix`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for coming back for me. If there is no postfix installed in my Ubuntu host, I don't think I can run the cp and ln command, right? I want to run the tail command and email the output in my cronjob and I want to install SSmtp only since I need to send only. How can I modify `tail -10000 /var/log/nginx/mydomain-access.log | awk '$11 !~ /google|bing|yahoo|yandex|mywebsite.com/' | awk '{print $11}' | tr -d '"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1000 | mail -s "Top 1000 Referers for Mydomain.com" me@mydomain.com` THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: You don't need to modify that line from `cron`. The only command in this line that sending email is the last one `mail` that by default using `sendmail` to delivery messages. If you don't have `posfix` installed and you wish to use `ssmtp` then the only thing you need to do is : `ln -sf /usr/sbin/ssmtp /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: BIG THANKS to you. You just save me a lot of sleepless nights. I cannot believe I am trying in the very wrong direction. Again, thank you SO MUCH for being so generous.

Comment: No problem, I glad I helped you